# Is there a way to run a groovy class without having the source code?

Tags: groovy

I have created a groovy file- MyGroovyFile.groovy.

MyGroovyFile.groovy:

```
import com.Thirdparty;
println 'Hello world';
```

Now I am compiling this file- `groovyc MyGroovyFile.groovy`. After compilation, MyGroovyFile.class is getting created.

Now I want to run this MyGroovyFile.class in a different folder/ different machine. But when I try to execute `groovy MyGroovyFile`, I am getting the error: `"Caught: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /path/to/file/filename ( /path/to/file/filename)".`

What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit 1:**

I imported a third-party class into my groovy source code. I tried to do what mathias suggested. `java -cp .:$GROOVY_HOME/lib/groovy-2.5.8.jar:/path/to/thirdparty.jar MyGroovyFile` This time I am getting NoClassDefFoundException.

Comment: *But when I try to do so* => How are you doing that?

Comment: `groovy MyGroovyFile`. I run this command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to run your groovy code on different machines and:

- you don't have any additional requirements forcing you to compile
- groovy and java is installed on all the machines you want to run on

then you don't need to compile the code (i.e. no need to run `groovyc`).

You can just run the code using:

```
─➤ groovy MyGroovyFile.groovy
```

If you need to compile the code, you can do something like:

```
─➤ groovyc MyGroovyFile.groovy 
─➤ java -cp .:/$GROOVY_HOME/lib/groovy-2.5.8.jar MyGroovyFile
Hello World!
─➤
```

in other words, if you want to run the groovy class from java, you need to include the groovy jar on the classpath.

Alternatively you can build a self contained jar file (commonly referred to as a "fat jar") which contains the groovy lib. One way to do this is via gradle. You would need gradle installed and then add a `build.gradle` file to your directory with something like the following in it:

```
plugins {
  id 'groovy'
  id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '5.2.0'
}

repositories { 
  jcenter()
}

dependencies { 
  implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.8'
}

sourceSets {
  main {
    groovy {
      srcDirs = ['.']
    }
  }
}

jar {
  manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'MyGroovyFile'
  }
}
```

After which you can build a fat jar via:

```
─➤ gradle shadow

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
```

and run the fat jar using:

```
─➤ java -jar build/libs/WhateverYourFatJarNameIs.jar 
Hello World!
```

Comment: @Mathias I was able to run my class with what you said. But when I add a 3rd party library to my groovy source code and run, it is throwing `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` exception. How can I solve this? (I have made some changes to my question)

Comment: If you run with `java` you need to add the external lib (and all its transitive dependencies) to your classpath. If you run with gradle you will need find your library on say maven central and add a line of the type `implementation '<lib-group>:<lib-name>:<lib-version>'` to the gradle build file.

Comment: I want to run with java command. I have added all the dependencies in my classpath and still not working. Please take a look at what I have done from [here](https://pastebin.com/W5Un21UH).